# Can I run JIRA on a shared hosting server?

Tags: hosting, jira

I purchased JIRA a few weeks ago to manage some projects and such and intended to put it on my shared web host.

However, it requires a Tomcat server instead of Apache. It comes with a packaged Tomcat server, but when I use this, I get errors about exceeding my accounts memory and CPU limits.

Are there any shared hosting providers that can host JIRA successfully? How can I tell which ones will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly doubt that any of the "general purpose" (read LAMP) shared hosting providers will let you run any long-running process, let alone tomcat/java, which are quite memory and CPU intensive. I have successfully run both JIRA and Confluence (same host, different java vm instances) on a [Linode 768](http://www.linode.com/index.cfm) with good performance. Of course with Linode, you'll need to take care of all the tasks involved with running your own server. If Linode isn't an option, it looks like Atlassian has a [directory of hosting providers](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=162718) that their products are known to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian also has their own hosted JIRA service, [JIRA Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/) - if that's of interest you might be able to switch over your license.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider a Virtual Private Server. It is still on a shared server (so less expensive) but gives you full control of your environment and you get root access and all that good stuff.

Comment: I tried a VPS from Rackspace Cloud (the $20/month one) and it couldn't handle it :(

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I'm currently looking for the same, and wanted to share [this post](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/62855-hosted-jira-in-15-minutes-for-5-per-month) in which a developer uses DigitalOcean's lowest-end server (512MB, 1-core) which costs only $5/mo. I haven't tried it myself yet (still exploring), but I figure if the $5/mo server works, then even if it's a bit too slow for my needs, the next model is $10/mo -- the same as Atlassian's own hosting but allowing full freedom & flexibility of your own server. On the whole I'm trying to shoot for < $10 for just that reason.

Others I've found:

- [DataShack](https://www.datashack.net/vps/) - 512MB at $4/mo
- [Linode][3] - 1GB at $10/mo (what [EEAA][4] suggested above)
- [Mozy][5] - Doesn't give specs, though. Actually found it via an add on this very page!

I'd post the links to the above services, but apparently ServerFault won't let me because I'm too new. Naturally.

I'll update this if I find anything better.

Comment: Hehehe, this works too:
  [3]: https://www.linode.com/pricing
  [4]: http://serverfault.com/users/20815/eeaa
  [5]: http://mozy.com/product/mozy/business

Comment: JIRA and Confluence are resource pigs. Good luck running it on a VPS with 512Mb - 1GB RAM.